# A prayer for the hostages

Tags: tefilla

Sivan Rahav Meir wrote:

> Rami Goren found a prayer that his grandfather Rav Shlomo Goren—who
> was the Chief Rabbi of the IDF from 1948-1968—composed for the safe
> return of prisoners captured in the Yom Kippur War 50 years ago. Rami
> revised his grandfather's prayer a little, feeling that we could
> benefit from reciting it now:
>
> ```
> May the One who blessed our forefathers, Avraham, Yitzchak and
> Ya'akov, Moshe, Aharon, David and Shlomo, may He bless and protect and
> rescue our dear sons and daughters, soldiers of the IDF, and all
> others fighting for the security of our nation and our land and our
> citizens—young and old, men, women and children—who are in terrible
> distress and subject to grave danger in captivity. May the Holy One
> blessed be He be filled with compassion for them, sustain them and
> strengthen them, revive their spirit and their hope, rescue them from
> captivity, bring them from constriction to comfort, from being
> hostages to redemption, and may the Lord send healing from heaven to
> the wounded among them, healing of the body and of the soul and may
> all of them return quickly to their homes and to their land, healthy
> and whole, for long life and for peace, and may the words of the
> prophet come true for them: “To bind the wounded of heart, to proclaim
> release of the captives.”
> ```

```
Is this a halachically appropriate prayer to utter?
```

Comment: What is wrong with saying such a prayer? Everyone can compose and say one (there is even a special place in the shmonei esrei for it) - even more so when composed by a great man such as R Goren. Can you say more about your are concerned about?